# Звук повторно воспроизводится если я сменю сцену и вернусь обратно Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d-android

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int isOn;
    private void Start()
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("off"))
        {
            isOn=PlayerPrefs.GetInt("off");
            if(isOn==1)
            {
                AudioListener.volume = 1f;
            }
            else if(isOn==0)
            {
                AudioListener.volume = 0f;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isOn = 1;

        }
    }
    public void OnOffSounds()
    {
        if(isOn==0)
        {
            AudioListener.volume = 1f;
            
            isOn=1;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("off", isOn=1);
        }
        else if(isOn==1)
        {
            AudioListener.volume=0f;
            
            
            isOn=0;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("off", isOn=0);
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: в настройках источника звука есть автоплей, отключи его